# Json Response format Incorrect

Tags: arrays, json, xsd, wso2

Team, I'm facing the Issue of Response Format Incorrect Error, Can any one convert into the proper response. Thanks in advance.

Response XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="jsonObject">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="ImranBillId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="ImranGuid" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="StatusCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="Message" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

JSON Response Expected:

```
[
    {
        "ImranBillId": "11800010310",
        "ImranGuid": "ad722dda-fdca-e811-a950-000d3aa154bb",
        "StatusCode": 2,
        "Message": "This Bill is already Reconciled"
    }
]
```

Actual Result:

```
{
    "fault": {
        "code": 400,
        "type": "Imran Bill Service",
        "message": "Runtime Error",
        "description": "Response format is incorrect"
    }
}
```

Comment: is this entire xsd schema? it seems that the tag `<xs:complexType>` was never opened

Comment: <xs: complexType > is there on the top, due to length issue Stack Overflow  is not accepeting

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="jsonObject">
    <xs:complexType>

Comment: Can you provide the sequence that you are using? It sounds like you are not setting the messageType and ContentType properties, but without the sequence we cannot tell where you are going wrong.